# In tcl, how do I write to a variable in which shell I am?

Tags: shell, tcl

In a tcl shell, I want to store in a variable in which shell I am. This script is also meant to be run by others and I need to check in which shell they are.

I tried using exec, but I am having trouble storing the results in a variable that I can compare to a string, basically, I want to find out whether a user is in bash, csh or ksh. Users switch between shells, so it is necessary to identify the active shell they are in. I tried:

```
set shell [exec echo \$0]
puts stdout "echo $shell;"

if { [string first "bash" $shell] != -1 } {
puts stdout "echo should be bash, is $shell;"
} elseif { [string first "ksh" $shell] != -1 } {      
puts stdout "echo should be KSH, is $shell;"
} else {
puts stdout "echo should be csh, is $shell;"
}
```

This unfortunately only writes the string $0 into shell and not the actual shell. Is there another way of doing this? For context, this is for a modulefile on linux, which allows me (and others) to set an appropriate environment for a specific software package.

modulefile has

set shell [module-info shell]

but that does not give the active shell.

EDIT:

To clarify, I want to know in which shell I am, so that I can run

```
something.sh if I am in bash
something.ksh if I am in ksh
something.csh if I am in csh
```

all those scripts have to do slightly different things before the software people want to run can be run in the given shell. This would be invoked in a terminal and the software people want to use would be run in that terminal as well.

Thanks!

Comment: *No* program can modify a parent process's internal state without that parent process's active participation. Thus, you can't write a script in *any* language -- tcl, bash, Python, C, nothing -- that changes state of the shell that invoked it as a subprocess, or otherwise runs builtins in that shell.

Comment: ...that's why when you run `ssh-agent`, for example, you need to run something like `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, to cause the shell to evaluate `ssh-agent`'s output as commands; otherwise, it would have no possible way to modify the invoking shell to set the environment variables used to address the daemon it spawns.

Comment: ...wait, do you mean "in which shell I am" meaning the name of the parent process? Because *that* you can look up, by walking the process tree (though it won't necessarily be a shell at all; programs on UNIX can be started by non-shell processes).

Comment: It would do a lot of good if we understood the context. That said, *in general* for use cases where you need to modify the state of a parent's shell, the practice is to have the parent process either source in a different script (providing a `foo.bash`, a `foo.ksh`, a `foo.csh`, etc) as appropriate to their use case, or to otherwise have the shell script invoking the code in question be responsible for describing what kind of output it needs (as is done in the `ssh-agent` case I described above, with `-s` specifying that the desired output is for the Bourne/POSIX shell family).

Comment: hi @CharlesDuffy thanks for your answers, I added a bit of clarification why I need to know in which shell I am. To summarize, depending on what shell the user is in, different scripts have to be run.

Comment: That's irrelevant here, when you're in a subprocess and not in the calling shell at all.

Comment: To explain more clearly what I mean -- the only point to using a different `foo.bash`, `foo.ksh`, `foo.csh`, etc. is to source the right file into the current interpreter, but you can only source in a file *from the process itself*, not from a subprocess, and your TCL interpreter is a subprocess.

Comment: So *even if you did* know the correct shell, that knowledge would be useless to you. Please reread my earlier comments, which explain further.

Comment: It would be better to write the shell script in portable bourne shell and use /bin/sh instead of having multiple copies.

Comment: @BradLanam, POSIX sh != Bourne. The last system to ship Bourne as /bin/sh was SunOS; even Solaris eventually switched. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98892/why-does-no-one-use-the-true-bourne-shell-as-bin-sh and especially the comments on the accepted answer.

Comment: That's naive.  There are many bourne shell compatible shells (I know a little something about them).  Instead of creating a new mess of code trying to determine the active shell and maintain multiple shell scripts, it is better to write a portable bourne shell script and not have the issue.  I can write a portable bourne shell script that runs on any system.   I cannot do such with a posix shell.

Comment: I can't test so I wont do this as an answer, but you could get the parent process ID and look that up in `/proc` to get the name of the executable. This is going to be messy but it is basically the only sane-ish way to get the invoking shell (as opposed to login shell)...

Answer (score 1):

If what you wish to know is the value of the SHELL environment variable, Tcl provides a global array named `env` which contains the environment that the Tcl shell was started in. Try:

```
set myshell $::env(SHELL)
```

You will need to handle cases where SHELL is not defined, but that's another question.

Comment: hey andy, thanks for your comment! I tried that, but this will only give me the login shell of the user. If my login shell is bash and I switch to ksh, $SHELL will still return bash. With $0 I can get the active shell, or with something like that: ps -p $$ | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 6 
but I don't know how to write that into a tcl variable.

Best

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the parent of the tcl process is the shell, but does avoid the issue with $::env(SHELL):

```
stemoo01 > echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
stemoo01 > tclsh
% puts $::env(SHELL)
/bin/tcsh
% regexp {(\w+)$} [exec ps -hp [exec ps -o ppid= -p [pid]]] all match
1
% puts $match
csh

stemoo01 > bash
bash-4.2$ echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
bash-4.2$ tclsh
% puts $::env(SHELL)
/bin/tcsh
% regexp {(\w+)$} [exec ps -hp [exec ps -o ppid= -p [pid]]] all match
1
% puts $match
bash
```